# CI couldn't output my joined table

Tags: codeigniter

i have three tables book_tbl(book_ID,title);isbn_tbl(isbn_id,isbn_number,book_ID//foriegn key) and         lastly author_tbl(author_ID,author_name,book_ID//foriegn key)

```
model:
 function getRecord(){
    $data = array(
        'book_tbl.title',
        'author_tbl.author_name',
        'isbn_tbl.isbn_number'
        );
    $this->db->select($data);
    $this->db->from('book_tbl');
    $this->db->join('author_tbl','author_tbl.book_ID=book_tbl.book_ID','inner');
    $this->db->join('isbn_tbl','book_tbl.book_ID=isbn_tbl.book_ID','inner');
    $this->db->order_by('book_tbl.book_ID','ASC');
    return $query = $this->db->get()->result();
}

controller:
public function display_book(){

    $data = array();
    if($query = $this->module->getRecord()){

        $data['result'] = $query;

    }

    #$this->success($data);
}

view:
<?php if(isset($result) && ($result->num_rows() > 0)) : foreach ($result as $row) : ?>
<?php 
echo $row->title;
echo $row->author_name;
echo $row->isbn_number;
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else : ?>

<h2>No Record</h2>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what is error show up? to find manipulated query debug with `echo $this->db->last_query()`

Comment: actually its logical error, i mean i couldn't fetch the record

Comment: <h1>Read all books</h1>

<?php if(isset($result) && ($result->num_rows() > 0)) : foreach ($result as $row) : ?>
<?php 
    echo $row->title;
    echo $row->author_name;
    echo $row->isbn_number;
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else : ?>

 <h2>No Record</h2>

<?php endif; ?>

Comment: only the h1 and h2 tag are visible T_T

Comment: suppose `author_tbl`, `isbn_tbl` tables have not related data, and you have used `INNER` join that is return both table matched data

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query() where should i put this piece of code?

Comment: those three table are related, using the book_ID,

Comment: in controller inside `if($query = $this->module->getRecord()){`

Comment: nothings happened T_T

Comment: Error
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 6
STR: ->
SQL: $this->db->last_query()

SQL query:

$this->db->last_query()

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$this->db->last_query()' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRecord(){
$data = array(
    'book_tbl.title',
    'author_tbl.author_name',
    'isbn_tbl.isbn_number'
    );
$this->db->select($data);
$this->db->from('book_tbl');
$this->db->join('author_tbl','author_tbl.book_ID=book_tbl.book_ID','inner');
$this->db->join('isbn_tbl','book_tbl.book_ID=isbn_tbl.book_ID','inner');
$this->db->order_by('book_tbl.book_ID','ASC');
$query = $this->db->get();
//echo query here by $this->db->last_query();
}
```

`$this->db->last_query();` echo you last query copy and paste it in your mysql and check that is data is coming ?

if yes then check the **num_rows()** in the model and as per that only display result as it will be well maintained code.

Comment: and then i will call the model function itself?

Comment: what does your query output in mysql

Comment: Error
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 6
STR: ->
SQL: $this->db->last_query()SELECT * FROM `author_tbl` WHERE 1

SQL query: Documentation

$this->db->last_query()SELECT * FROM `author_tbl` WHERE 1

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$this->db->last_query()SELECT * FROM `author_tbl` WHERE 1' at line 1

Comment: sorry for that i put it in my author table

Comment: There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 6
STR: ->
SQL: $this->db->last_query()

SQL query:

$this->db->last_query()

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$this->db->last_query()' at line 1

Comment: Error
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 6
STR: ->
SQL: $this->db->last_query()

SQL query:

$this->db->last_query()

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$this->db->last_query()' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

so you have error in query not in Code so please make query first in MySQL if the output comes then integrate in CodeIgniter model

```
function getRecord(){
$data = array(
'book_tbl.title',
'author_tbl.author_name',
'isbn_tbl.isbn_number'
);
$this->db->select($data);
$this->db->from('book_tbl');
$this->db->join('author_tbl','author_tbl.book_ID=book_tbl.book_ID');
$this->db->join('isbn_tbl','isbn_tbl.book_ID=book_tbl.book_ID');
$this->db->order_by('book_tbl.book_ID','ASC');
$res = $this->db->get();
    if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
        return $res->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

try this may be helpful

Comment: how about my controller? is there anything i can change?

Comment: public function display_book(){
   $data['result'] = $this->module->getRecord();
   $this->load->view('page',$data);
}

in View check if($result !== false){ //then dispaly data; }

Comment: h1>Read all books</h1>

<?php if(isset($result) && $result !== FALSE) : foreach ($result as $row) : ?>
<?php 
    echo $row->title;
    echo $row->author_name;
    echo $row->isbn_number;
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else : ?>

 <h2>No Record</h2>

<?php endif; ?>

Comment: by the way, why did you remove the inner in the join? any significant?

Comment: it is not required to write inner. MySQL understand automatically.

And does my answer helped you ?